# How to avoid long fights in crystal pvp

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play vanilla crystal pvp a lot. If you don't know what that is, here's an example:

I fight like this in a lot of survival servers, but everyone brings 12+ totems of undying to fights and nobody ever dies because people have learned to hotkey totems extremely fast. When they run out of totems in their inventory, they simply regear from their ender chest, and when their armor is about to break, they just mend it with experience bottles. With automated farms, everyone has shulker boxes full of totems, god gear, experience bottles, and end crystals.

Maybe I'm not getting something, but is there a way for me to win in a fight without just outgearing the other person? Fights can last as long as 30+ minutes even without regears, it's getting really boring.